# Nginx is not serving django projects that is running on uwsgi

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi

I have 2 django projects that are configured to be served on sockets.

They are at the same server. Django project names are **proj1** and **proj2**. So i gave them 2 different names **proj1.cr.tm** and **proj2.cr.tm** on **/etc/hosts** file and both of them are pointing to same local **127.0.0.1** address. So when i ping **proj1.cr.tm** it pings 127.0.0.1 , when i ping **proj2.cr.tm** it pings 127.0.0.1 also. So the thing i want is serving 2 projects on these two different domain names on same server ip on port 80. The differentiation with names and projects will be made by nginx.

I also prepared 2 nginx configurations **proj1.conf** and **proj2.conf** under **/etc/nginx/conf.d** directory and added **proj1.cr.tm** and **proj2.cr.tm** as servers in these configurations. I also included them in main **nginx.conf** file  under **/etc/nginx/nginx.conf** file.

I also prepared 2 ini files for uwsgi and run uwsgi with emperor. When i run uwsgi and nginx i can see that socket files are created.
And i can also see nginx is working on http:/127.0.0.1 with default nginx page. I also see that uwsgi processes with project modules are working in linux processes behind. But when i try http://proj1.cr.tm and http://proj2.cr.tm addresses i still cannot see my django web sites. I still see nginx default page.

I checked directory and socket and conf files and ini files permissions. They look ok. When i run django sites with runserver or when i run them with **"uwsgi --http :8081 --module proj1.wsgi"** they are working. But i cannot serv them with nginx.

UPDATE :

nginx config for proj 1 :

```
    server {
        listen          80;
        server_name proj1.cr.tm;

        access_log      /var/log/nginx/proj1_access.log;
        error_log       /var/log/nginx/proj1_errors.log;

        sendfile        on;
        client_max_body_size 20M;
        keepalive_timeout  0;

        location = favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

        location /static/ {
                root /home/proj1/work/proj1;
        }
        location /media/ {
                root /home/proj1/work/proj1;
        }

        location / {
                include uwsgi_params;
                uwsgi_read_timeout 9000;
                uwsgi_send_timeout 9000;
                uwsgi_connect_timeout 9000;
                uwsgi_pass unix:/run/uwsgi/proj1.sock;
        }
}
```

nginx config for proj 2 :

```
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name proj2.cr.tm;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/proj2-nec_access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/proj2-nec_errors.log;

        location = favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

        location /static/ {
                root /home/proj2/work/proj2;
        }

        location /user/ {
                include uwsgi_params;
                uwsgi_pass unix:/run/uwsgi/proj2.sock;
                uwsgi_read_timeout 900;
        }

        location / {
                include uwsgi_params;
                uwsgi_pass unix:/run/uwsgi/proj2.sock;
        }
}
```

uwsgi ini conf for proj1 :

```
    [uwsgi]
py-autoreload = 2
project = proj1
username = proj1
base = /home/%(username)

chdir = %(base)/work/%(project)
home = %(base)/Env/%(project)
module = %(project).wsgi:application

master = true
processes = %k

uid = %(username)
socket = /run/uwsgi/%(project).sock
chown-socket = %(username):nginx
chmod-socket = 666
vacuum = true
#logto = /var/log/uwsgi/%(project).log
```

uwsgi ini conf for proj2 :

```
    [uwsgi]
py-autoreload = 2
project = proj2
username = proj2
base = /home/%(username)

chdir = %(base)/work/%(project)
home = %(base)/Env/%(project)
module = %(project).wsgi:application

master = true
processes = %k

uid = %(username)
socket = /run/uwsgi/%(project).sock
chown-socket = %(username):nginx
chmod-socket = 666
vacuum = true
#logto = /var/log/uwsgi/%(project).log
```

nginx conf :

```
    #   * For  information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you share the configs?

Comment: Hello Shawn, i added configurations into the post .